# Java synchronization on static and nonstatic methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm little confused about behaviour for synhronization (static and non static method).

For example:

1.

```
    class MyClass  {
  ...
  public synchronized static someMethod() {
    ...
  }
  public static someMethod2() {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

So if thread A call someMethod1(), does thread B have lock on someMethod2()?

2.

```
     class MyClass  {
  ...
  public synchronized someMethod() {
    ...
  }
  public someMethod2() {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

If we have MyClass a = new MyClass(),thread A call method someMethod(),does thread have lock on someMethod2()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both is no. Synchronization is a cooperative mechanism. Synchronizing on an instance or class doesn't prevent other threads from calling another method unless that method also synchronizes on the same monitor.

Answer (score 0):

In both of your questions the answer is `No`: thread B won't be locked on method `someMethod2` since this method is not synchronized. 
Synchronization and related locks will be working only when both threads will call `someMethod`.

The only difference in this case is the target that will be locked. A synchronized method uses the method receiver as a lock (i.e. `this` for non static methods, and the enclosing class for static methods)

Comment: Synchronization doesn't block invocation of unsynchronized methods.

Comment: Thanks, modified the answer. I didnt understand the question correctly

Answer (score 0):

No, another method is free to lock in these cases. A thread can get a lock for the static method when another thread lock non static method of the class. These methods have different monitors.

When a static method is synchronized it's synchronize on a class. That means while execution of a static method the whole class is blocked. So other static synchronized methods are also blocked. In other case when a not static method is synchronized it's synchronize on an instance. All synchronized methods of only this specific object are blocked.

Comment: But the other method is not synchronized.